# Cloudflare individual file purging rate limited

Tags: cloudflare

When I try to purge cache for multiple files on Cloudflare I often get error response:

```
{"request":{"act":"zone_file_purge"},"result":"error","msg":"File purge rate limited."}
```

What can I do to not get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there was 50 purge URLs/minute limit.

I also found that this limit is only there for old API calls (which I used) - URL: 
https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html

Upgrading to https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/ fixed the issue.